# How do I test if a variable does not equal a lot of variables - Angular

Tags: angular

I would like to know if there is a simpler way to write this? because the code becomes too long:

```
<div *ngIf="value.data != '17' || value.data != '18' || value.data != '19' || value.data != '20'"</div>
```

Is there a way to abbreviate and not write so many times || value.data =! ...?

Thanks you!

Comment: If you are looking for range check `*ngIf="!(val>=17 && val<=20)"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an array to hold the values you want to check against. And use the includes method.

In TS:

```
   let arr = [17,18,19];
```

In HTML:

```
*ngIf="!arr.includes(value.data)"
```